# What is the best practice for isolating code outside of a project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am currently building a base application for my development shop. All projects turn around the same core business, and the security may vary from a requirement to another. We have determined four types of security strategy. What I am looking for is to develop a SecurityUtils JAR file in which all my logic would be implemented, and then, all my projects would use it as a dependency/reference.

Question is: What are the best practices for that kind of work?

My security strategy requires the following things:

- Current user id (request.getRemoteUser() provided by the container
  through JCIFS)
- Http Session User entity bean
- User session bean / service
- Role entity bean
- Role session bean / service
- Utility methods
  for querying LDAP using spring-ldap (find user in AD, gather user
  groups from AD, detect user location, etc.)

Admin users can manage roles and users from the Web application. They can check or uncheck features for each roles defined in the database. Each role is linked on a Active Directory group so the matching is done during the login sequence, and then permissions are set in the user's session for later use.

I am not too sure about the session bean and EJB part of the strategy. Should I let the it within the project or isolate it into the SecurityUtils JAR?

My specs:

- Spring MVC 4.0.3 (Spring Security & Spring LDAP)
- Thymeleaf for templates/views
- EJB3 for persistence
- jBoss 4.2.3GA application server
- PostgreSQL 9.0.3 database

Thank you for help

Charles